# Dynamic routing with NGINX

Tags: nginx

I am an amateur of NGINX, I want to setup NGINX as a Reverse Proxy for my web server.
I would like to know that the NGINX these things as listed below:

When a browser send request with URL: http://nginxproxy.com/client/1.2.3.4/, this request should be passed to the client with IP 1.2.3.4 http://1.2.3.4/, the browser should still show the URL nginxproxy/client/1.2.3.4/
And the same for:

- nginxproxy.com/client/2.3.4.5 --> //2.3.4.5
- nginxproxy.com/client/2.3.4.6 --> //2.3.4.6

All the others requests that doesn't mach the pattern should come to my default server myserver.

Can I do this by using NGINX?

After researching, I tried with the below configuration:
But unlucky, It doesn't work. The address was changed to http:/1.2.3.4 on browser's address bar, instead of http:/nginxproxy.com/client/1.2.3.4 as expected.

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location ~ ^/client {       
        rewrite ^/client/?(.*) /$2 break;
        proxy_pass $scheme://$1;             
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myserver.com;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have tried something?

Comment: Yes, I tried it by using rewrite mode but unlucky. At the address was changed to http://1.2.3.4 on browser's address bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Below is my procedure
 location ~ ^/client {
  rewrite ^/client/?(.*) /$2 break;
  proxy_pass $scheme://$1;
 }

Comment: Modify your post. It's impossible to read code in comments

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen. I modified my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing some more research and based on @Cole input, here is my answer:

```
location ~ ^/client/(?<site>[^/]+)/? {
    rewrite ^.*\/client\/(?<site>[^\/]+)\/?(.*) /$2 break; #passing all the remaining request URIs after <site> group to client server
    proxy_pass $scheme://$site;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host/client/$site; #this help to keep the address as it is on the browser's address bar
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;             
}

location / {
    proxy_pass $scheme://myserver.com
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    listen  80;

    location /client/ {
        rewrite ^/client/(?<site>[^/]+)/? $scheme://$site;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://myserver.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cole, it's very close my answer. However, If I remove the rewrite the request uri /client/1.2.3.4 will be passed to my client server. Like this: [http://1.2.3.4/client/1.2.3.4/index.html](http://1.2.3.4/client/1.2.3.4/index.html)

Comment: I've added an external rewrite. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @Cole for your help. Finally I found my solution based on your input.